# Issue with share only text on Facebook using FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

In my application i want to share only text on facebook. For that i am using FacebookSDK.

My Code for that is as below:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                   @"name" :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Jinx Share"],
                   @"caption" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
                   @"description" :@"Some text to share",
                   @"picture" : @"",
                   @"link" : @"",
                   };


     // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];
         }
         else if(session.isOpen)
         {

             // Invoke the dialog
             [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                    parameters:params
                                                       handler:
              ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                  if (error) {
                      //NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");

                  } else {
                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                          //NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");

                      } else {
                          //NSLog(@"Story published.");

                      }
                  }}];
         }

     }];
```

But when facebook share dialogue opens, it does not show any text there. Please see below screenshot

[image]

And if i gave any link in "picture" parameter then it shows the text. But i don't want any image to be shown. I just want only text to share on facebook.

What is wrong with my code ? Could someone give me solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the latest Facebook SDK from the month of April, Facebook does not allow your app to pre-fill any content to be shared. This is inconsistent with Facebook Platform Policy, [see Facebook Platform Policy, 2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill). Also refer this [Sharing through Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios).

Answer (score 0):

This API is deprecated to share the pre-selected text in native Share dialogue. You can use Graph API with custom story to share the pre-selected text:
Here is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/ios